# Imported Blender modular mesh lighting/shadows issue - Unity

Tags: unity, rendering, lighting, blender, materials

Hi I've very recently started using Unity and am creating a game level. I've created my environment in blender and am currently using a modular design as I'd like to include destructible environments.

I've applied test textures and colours to the mesh but have noticed problems when importing into unity.

In blender the lighting appears to cast shadows smoothly across the modular design, but once imported into unity I get random "light spots" and consecutive pieces appear slightly different shades in places.

Each module of a particular type shares a linked material and texture.

I've attached the Blender render first and then the Unity render (they have different lighting as I haven't added all the lights to blender, but the difference is obvious)

The walls are made up of cuboids 2.4 x 1.0 x 0.15

And the floors 1.0 x 1.0 x 0.1

It seems that some of the 'pieces' are receiving/casting shadows differently.

[image: Blender Render]
[image: Unity Render]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've solved most of the issues.

The very light wall pieces on the left of the unity render were caused by them actually being duplicate pieces. Deleting the duplicates solved that issue.

I then swapped my Main camera rendering path setting to "Vertex Lit" instead of "Forward".

The other probs seem to have been caused by the point lights. I had the ranges high on these at and the intensities low. By decreasing the ranges and increasing the intensities and then adding in additional point lights to the darker sections of the level I have managed to almost remove the probs completely.

[image: New unity Render]

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve your problem. Please accept your own answer, this marks your question as answered and prevents the website from automatically bringing it up to the front page every now and then. Thank you